# Strange order when retrieves data from android database

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to get data from my database using SQLDatabase.query method:

```
public Cursor getList() {
    DataProvider.DBHelper mDBHelper = DataProvider.getDBHelper();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(ShotsTable.TABLE_NAME, 
                    new String[]{ShotsTable.JSON}, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    ShotsTable.VIEWS + " DESC");
}


private List<Shots> getAllFromDB() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Cursor cursor = new ShotsDataHelper().getList();
    List<Shots> data = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            data.add(gson.fromJson(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ShotsDataHelper.ShotsTable.JSON)),
            Shots.class);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}


public void insert(Shots shots) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ShotsTable.ID, shots.getId());
    contentValues.put(ShotsTable.VIEWS, Integer.valueOf(shots.getViews_count()));
    contentValues.put(ShotsTable.COMMENTS, Integer.valueOf(shots.getComments_count()));
    contentValues.put(ShotsTable.LIKES, Integer.valueOf(shots.getLikes_count()));
    contentValues.put(ShotsTable.JSON, shots.getJson());
    insert(contentValues);      // insert into database using getContentResolver().insert(getContentUri(), contentValues);
}
```

and this is my table:

```
SQLiteTable TABLE = new SQLiteTable(TABLE_NAME)
                    .addColumn(ID, Column.DataType.TEXT)
                    .addColumn(VIEWS, Column.DataType.INTEGER)
                    .addColumn(COMMENTS, Column.DataType.INTEGER)
                    .addColumn(LIKES, Column.DataType.INTEGER)
                    .addColumn(JSON, Column.DataType.TEXT);
```

However, when the application loads data from database, it retrieved the data successfully, but the order here is strange(ordered by views I think), and the list looks like this(VIEWS listed below, returned from method getAllFromDB() above):

976

958

956

927

925

903

2115

1978

1936

1589

1574

1487

1363

1298

1265

1210

1130

1106

1104

1081

And the Cursor in getList() contains mQuery: "SQLiteQuery: SELECT json FROM shots ORDER by views DESC"

I wonder whether I do some wrong operation with database, but the desc order of data here is really strange, for datas that views_count are smaller than 1000, they have a desc order and for datas that views_count are greater than 1000, they also have a desc order too.

Answer (score 0):

You should post a little more, which query return which output. 
This output that you paste could suit for your data order by ID which is in your case string (I don't recommend this (long is more suitable type, but if you know what are you doing is ok)).

So the displayed numbers are alphabetically sorted; so order work correctly. Because asci value of '1' is lover then value of '9' so the number 19999 will appeare before number 9.

Comment: I have the same idea with you that numbers are alphabetically sorted not numerically sorted. But I query the dataset with column VIEWS which datatype is already Integer here and it still returns the output with numbers sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing json column type to integer, or using the following:

ORDER BY CAST(json AS int)

Comment: Well it works. the list sorted by column VIEWS correctly.But I can't understand why cast json to int makes sense. I insert some data in json format into column JSON. By the way, what if I want to sort numerically by column LIKES or COMMENTS?

Comment: Sorting by likes or comments should work because they are already cast as integers...but if not you can try the same that worked for you above.  Also, if this worked for you can you please choose it as the correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: I make a silly mistake here and I don't think this should be the correct answer, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering myself but I really make a silly mistake here. I forget to update the table so the query may sort the dataset by column VIEWS as TEXT, not INTEGER. After changing the table, it works fine.